# How to identify coding frame of gene in BioPython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am using BioPython to loop through open reading frames in a GenBank file. More specifically, I consider features that are annotated as 'CDS' in GenBank. So my code is of the type:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
gbk_dat = SeqIO.read(genbank_filepath, 'genbank')

for feature in gbk_dat.features:
    if feature.type == 'CDS':
         # Identify coding frame
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to identify which coding frame a gene is in versus the whole genome? Ie. if a gene starts at position 1 of the genome, it would be in coding frame 1, if it started at 2, in coding frame 2, if at 5, then frame 2 as well etc. (I know I can script this relatively easily but I like to rely on BioPython as it tends to be cleaner when sharing code later.)

Comment: Perhaps to clarify further, my question relates to identifying the frames of two overlapping genes. In some cases this can be tedious because some coding sequences have frameshifts within them (such as the bacterial prfA sequence). So the frame of the first codon thus may not correspond to the frame of the last codon. I was wondering if BioPython can take care of this automatically?

Comment: When you look at the genbank file -- there is a line that will tell you the codon_start position. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain this is what you need, but in the genbank file, a CDS region (associated with a gene) would look like this:

```
 gene            1012..1356
                 /locus_tag="L_00015"
 CDS             1012..1356
                 /locus_tag="L_00015"
                 /inference="ab initio prediction:Prodigal:2.6"
                 /inference="protein motif:Pfam:PF05136.7"
                 **/codon_start=1** 
                 /transl_table=11
                 /product="Phage portal protein, lambda family"
                 /protein_id="C:L_00015"
                 /translation="MIGVFDKLEERVIGARGIIVEPQPLRKNGEMAAELAADIRRLWA
                 EWSVSPDVTGQYTRPVLERLLLRTWLRDGEVFAQMVSGAGNGLERTAECHSGLRRWSR
                 ILFPSPLMNPPD"
```

There is a line (/codon_start=1) that tells you the gene's reading frame. If you would like to automatically snag that information, you can do so with the following code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
gbk_dat = SeqIO.read(genbank_filepath, 'genbank')

for feature in gbk_dat.features:
    if feature.type == 'CDS':
        print(feature.qualifiers.get('codon_start')))
```

As for the overlapping issue...can you post an example genbank file?